# VBA copy Excel table to existing Powerpoint table on a specific slide - keep destination formatting

Tags: excel

Good afternoon!

I have been trying to use VBA to copy a table from Excel to an already created table (Table 9) on slide 30 in an already opened Powerpoint presentation (using Excel and Powerpoint 2010). I am also trying to keep the original Powerpoint formatting for the data and table.

I have tried multiple different approaches with no luck .... even trying to just update one value in the table but isn't working either.  I have to update multiple tables in this presentation from excel.

I tried the Paste Link as well but this is not a good solution as the presentation may change.

Hopefully someone smarter than I am can be of help with this.

```
Set pp_App = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
pp_App.Visible = True

Worksheets("SMID Basket").Select
Worksheets("SMID Basket").Range("I5").Copy ' ))))))))))) works )))))))))))))))

pp_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(30).Select
pp_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(30).Shapes("Table 9").Table.Cell(2, 2).Select ' (((((((((( doesn't work (((((((((((

With Selection
    .PasteSpecial ppPasteDefault
    '.PasteSpecial ppPasteText
    ' .PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault
    ' .PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteShape
End With
```

Love this forum .... look at it all of the time when stuck with VBA coding.

Thank you so much for your kind assistance with this!

Ladyred

I tried to post the code but keep getting error messages :-(

Comment: Does the size of each table change? E.g. will it have 5 rows today and then (potentially) 6 rows tomorrow?

Comment: Not in this table.  Other tables in the ppt can vary.

Comment: This is actually really hard to answer because you're talking about an entire solution rather than a focussed problem to an issue.  I've done this sort of thing before by using the PowerPoint application library from Excel to populate data into a presentation.  I just did some basic prototyping (after not having done it for about 10 years) and I got it to populate a table with some basic data.  You need to look at the VBA objects for PPT much like you do with Excel.  You can make a reference in Excel to PPT by going to Tools -> References and selecting "Microsoft PowerPoint".

Comment: From there, you can open a presentation and then play with the shapes inside on each slide.

Comment: Thank you for your time answering my question.  I tried to copy the code but kept getting error messages.

Comment: What does the error say when you try and load the code in?

Comment: Set pp_App = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
pp_App.Visible = True

Worksheets("SMID Basket").Select
Worksheets("SMID Basket").Range("I5").Copy
' ))))))))))) works )))))))))))))))
pp_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(30).Select
pp_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(30).Shapes("Table 9").Table.Cell(2, 2).Select

' (((((((((( doesn't work (((((((((((
With Selection
    .PasteSpecial ppPasteDefault
'    .PasteSpecial ppPasteText
 '   .PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault
 '    .PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteShape    
End With

Comment: I was able to put code in comment!

Comment: Got it working up to the ((( doesn't work((( .... the selection of the table in powerpoint works but can't seem to get the pastespecial to work .... I tried different things .... any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't select and PasteSpecial like that.  I'd just insert the .Text value of each cell into each cell in the presentation.  You have more control over the format, etc. and you're only hitting one cell each time with basic, formatted text.  If you need to do other things like add rows/columns to match your source data then you can do that too.

Comment: You're on the right track though.

Comment: Set PP_App = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
PP_App.Visible = True
 
Worksheets("SMID Basket").Select
Worksheets("SMID Basket").Range("I5").Copy

PP_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(30).Select

PP_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(30).Shapes("Table 9").Table.Cell(2, 2).Select

PP_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(30).Shapes("Table 9").Table.Cell(2, 2).Select
PP_App.ActiveWindow.View.Paste

Comment: Got it working!!! Thank you so much for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use Text Frame Property of Cell, check below snippet
Shape is PowerPoint Table with ShapeType

```
     i = 1
    For j = config.StartingColumn To dataRange.columns.Count + config.StartingColumn - 1
        Set tempRange = dataRange.Cells(i, j - config.StartingColumn + 1)
        With shape.Table.Cell(i, j).shape
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = tempRange.Offset(-1, 0).Value
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 10
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
        End With
    Next
```